# Makefile crash on providing multiple dependencies

Tags: windows, c++11, makefile, mingw-w64

This is a simple `Makefile` I had written. To get it working on `mingw32-make` I had to replace the `@if [ ! -d $(OUTDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(notdir $(OUTDIR)); fi` calls with `ifneq` constructs. This is the file as now:

```
# This Makefile will build an application using the DLL.

SRCTREE :=  ./

CXX ?=      g++
AR ?=       ar

SRCDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)src
OUTDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)bin
OBJDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)obj
LIBDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)lib
INCDIR :=   $(SRCTREE)include

CFLAGS :=   -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
CFLAGS_EXTRA :=  -coverage
LFLAGS :=   -lgcov --coverage


dirs:
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/.)", "")
    -mkdir $(notdir $(OBJDIR))
endif
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(LIBDIR)/.)", "")
    -mkdir $(notdir $(LIBDIR))
endif
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(OUTDIR)/.)", "")
    -mkdir $(notdir $(OUTDIR))
endif

all: dirs use-static

use-shared: CFLAGS_EXTRA += -pthread -DMATRIX_USE_DLL -DDLL_IMPORTS
use-shared: LFLAGS := -L$(SRCTREE) -l:$(OUTDIR)/Matrix.so
use-shared: main

use-static: CFLAGS_EXTRA += -pthread
use-static: LFLAGS := $(LIBDIR)/Matrix.a
use-static: main

%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS_EXTRA) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $<

main: main.o
    $(CXX) -o $(OUTDIR)/$@ $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$^) $(LFLAGS) -s -pthread

clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJDIR)/main.o
    -rm -f $(OUTDIR)/main
    -rm -f $(LIBDIR)/Matrix.a
    -rm -f $(OUTDIR)/Matrix.so
```

When I run it like `mingw32-make all -n`, if the directories are not present, I get crash like: `mingw32-make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x00007FFE854CF15C)`. I cannot find what the problem could be. Could someone suggest what might be wrong?

Comment: Is this really and truly the makefile?

Comment: Sounds like you found a bug in make; no matter what makefile you give make, it should not crash.

Comment: What happens if you [simplify](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Like remove the `clean` rule? And the `use-shared` rule? And the `use-static` prerequisite of the `all` rule? And one or two of the `ifeq...endif` clauses?...

Comment: I tried removing some of the `ifeq...endif` clauses, but I get same error. Also, on running with `-d` option, make seems to be having difficulty resolving just at the implicit rule. Maybe stack issue? Bug, as MadScientist proposed? However, only `mingw32-make` seems to be struggling. Here's working run for GNU make: https://travis-ci.org/sauvik3/Matrix/jobs/348951272

Comment: I'm trying to get `gcov` working, but that is another issue.

Comment: I guess, I'm going to write this one off for now. I'll stick to the idea that resolution to multiple depths, especially with implicit rules may not work as expected. Resolving implicit rules causes more overhead and uses more of 'stack'-space. Somehow, still something doesn't seem right, as this depth only was limited to 4 levels, not anything particularly extraordinary. I might still expect some more clarification.